# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oTargetControl' of undefined

Tags: javascript, navigation, sapui5, router

When loading my application, I receive this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oTargetControl' of undefined"

I'm using Routing configurations (this is SAPui5 Application).

```
    "routing": {
        "config": {
            "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
            "viewType": "XML",
            "viewPath": "myNav.view",
            "controlId": "app",
            "controlAggregation": "pages"

        },
        "routes": [{
            "pattern": "",
            "name": "first",
            "target": "first"

        }, {
            "pattern": "",
            "name": "second",
            "target": "second"

        }],
        "targets": {
            "first": {
                "viewName": "First"
            },
            "second": {
                "viewName": "Second"

            }
        }

    }
```

My Component.js Code is

```
    UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
    this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");
    this.getRouter().initialize();
```

This is a simple navigation example and I have two Views (First and Second View).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you specify a root view?

You specified a controlId 'app' and a controlAggregation 'pages' for your routing. That means your Router will search for the control with the id 'app' and will try to replace the aggregation 'pages' of this control with the matching route.

I guess `oTargetControl` is the not-found control 'app' and that's why the error occurs.

Sth. like this should go in your applications config:

```
"rootView": "my.app.Root"
```

Secondly as Nabi already mentioned routing works strictly first match, first served, meaning that your view Second will NEVER be used. You either have to adapt patterns or use the greedy flag.

see https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/cf3c57c89ef0491793d1ce327ab4f9b2.html

Comment: Thanks for response, I've reviewed all config steps, and adjusted rootView which was different from controlID, and the error was happening because I  didn't put the app id on the view, so now I set the app id on the firstview and the error is not been showed more .

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 routes have the same pattern. Which of the routes do you expect to be matched in case of the empty hash (pattern="")? I guess this is causing the issue. Either make sure you have different patterns or use the [greedy](https://millermedeiros.github.io/crossroads.js/#crossroads-greedy) feature which is supported by the underlying library crossroads.js

Comment: Thanks by response Nabi, Even changing first pattern parameter, the error persists, any more suggestions?

Comment: have a look at what @cschuff answered. He has some good hints. Additionally, is the controlId you reference an App or an SpitApp etc.? This is because you are referencing the controlAggregation "pages", which means the corresponding control must have an aggregation "pages". This is true for the App, but not for the SplitApp. Could you please check this? Maybe you could also post your complete manifest.json file...

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added "async" : true property into routing

`

```
"routing": {
            "config": {
                "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
                "viewType": "XML",
                "viewPath": "sap.sapx5Exercise03_1.view",
                "controlId": "menu",
                "targetControl" : "app",
                "transition": "slide",
                "controlAggregation": "pages",
                "bypassed": {
                    "target": "notFound"
                },
                "async" : true

            },
```

`......
and remember that "controlId": "menu", value of property should be into your view

`

```
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="sap.sapx5Exercise03_1.controller.Menu"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1"
    >
    <App id="menu">
```

`......